# Why doesn't my Java exception print a stack trace when thrown inside a SwingWorker?

Tags: java, swing, exception

Why is it that when I wrap a SwingWorker around this code it no longer reports an exception being thrown?

```
import java.security.InvalidParameterException;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        IntegerString s = new IntegerString("EIGHT");
                        return null;
                    }

                }.execute();

            }

        });

    }

}

class IntegerString {

    public IntegerString(String s) {
        if (!isInteger(s)) {
            System.out.println("...throwing exception.");
            throw new InvalidParameterException("Thrown.");
        }
        // ...
    }

    static boolean isInteger(String str) {
        if (str == null) {
            return false;
        }
        int length = str.length();
        if (length == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        int i = 0;
        if (str.charAt(0) == '-') {
            if (length == 1) {
                return false;
            }
            i = 1;
        }
        for (; i < length; i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if (c <= '/' || c >= ':') {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not thrown or not reported as you expect it to?

Comment: It's not being reported. I assume it's being thrown but the stacktrace isn't printing.

Comment: My guess is that an exception is still thrown, but the internal handler's call to `doInBackground()` is wrapped in a try-catch statement designed to ignore exceptions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to call `get()` to retrieve any exceptions that occurred in `doInBackground()`. For example, you can do it in `done()` method, ie:

```
@Override
protected void done() {
    try {
        get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: but... is the exception logged to JUL or something like that?

Comment: @jaime not sure I understand who is logging to JUL. It is up to the implementation of `SwingWorker` to handle the exceptions. Exceptions that occur in `doInBackground()` are propagated to `done()` wrapped in `ExecutionException`. You can analyze nested exception and handle it as needed. Note that there is also a possibility of `InterruptedException`.

Comment: @jaime I meant *your* implementation of `SwingWorker`.

Comment: my question was if before letting me handle the exception, the library that controls the execution of my `SwingWorker` implementation was logging the exception stacktrace/message to any logger, as I prefer to be able to see in the console stacktraces for any unmanaged exceptions being triggered without having to "manage" the exception

Comment: @jaime I don't think there is logging done in `Executor`. I'm afraid I'm misinterpreting your question. Are you asking abount exceptions that are thrown from your implementation of `doInBackground()`?

Comment: Exactly, I was wondering if the `SwingWorker` executor was logging (to somewhere) exceptions thrown from `doInBackground()`, I guess the best would be to check the source code :)